# Wrong exponential fit with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I am trying to exponentially fit some data, but cannot seem to coerce `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to give me a pleasing result.

I have boiled down my code to the example below, including an empirically derived manual fit to the data.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy
import scipy.stats

x = [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
     43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
     61, 62, 63, 64]
y = [9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14,
     14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 27, 30, 31,
     32, 37, 37]

def fitting_function(x, a, b, c):
    return a * numpy.exp(b * x) + c

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='Original data')
OptimalValues, Covariance = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fitting_function, x, y)
plt.plot(x, fitting_function(x, *OptimalValues), '-',
         label='Fitted Curve (%0.2e*e^%sx+%0.2e)' % (OptimalValues[0],
                                              OptimalValues[1],
                                              OptimalValues[2]))
ManualFit = [0.1 * numpy.exp(0.09 * i) + 8 for i in x]
plt.plot(x, ManualFit, '-', label='Manual Fit (%s*e^%sx+%s)' % (0.1, 0.09, 8))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image: Result of the code above]

According to other answers here on Stack Overflow an obvious solution is to provide `curve_fit` with a reasonable initial guess.
If I do that by putting the below lines at the relevant place my code (lines 16 and 17) the interpreter complains about a `ValueError` because it somehow tries to broadcast the `guess` to `len(x)` or `len(y0` (i.e. *operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0) (40)*.

```
guess = (0.1, 0.1, 10)
OptimalValues, Covariance = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fitting_function, x, y,
                                                     p0=guess)
```

How can I get `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to give me a meaningful output in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your `x` and `y` lists into `numpy` arrays, and it will work fine. I found that to get a satisfactory fit, you do need to include your initial guess. So, this code:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy
import scipy.stats

x = numpy.array([25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
     43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
     61, 62, 63, 64])
y = numpy.array([9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14,
     14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 27, 30, 31,
     32, 37, 37])

def fitting_function(x, a, b, c):
    return a * numpy.exp(b * x) + c

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='Original data')

guess =(0.1,0.1,10)
OptimalValues, Covariance = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fitting_function, x, y,
                                                     p0=guess)

plt.plot(x, fitting_function(x, *OptimalValues), '-',
         label='Fitted Curve (%0.2e*e^%sx+%0.2e)' % (OptimalValues[0],
                                              OptimalValues[1],
                                              OptimalValues[2]))
ManualFit = [0.1 * numpy.exp(0.09 * i) + 8 for i in x]
plt.plot(x, ManualFit, '-', label='Manual Fit (%s*e^%sx+%s)' % (0.1, 0.09, 8))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Produces this plot:

[image]